# Why won't text center vertically in span

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<span class="or">
or
</span>
```

Styled like so:

```
.or {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This results in the following element.

[image]

Notice how the text itself is not quite vertically centered (even though the highlight of the text is centered). I've tried changing the `line-height` attribute and `vertical-align: middle;` among others but nothing seems to to do anything. How can I center the text in this div?

Comment: You're accomplished your job, but you don't pay attention for line-height.  Try to use [text-transform: uppercase;] to understand what I mean

Comment: I see that when I make it uppercase it fills the entire line height and is therefore centered. But I'm looking for a way to center the text itself while it is lower case

Comment: Then you have to disable "align-items: center" property and then adjust "line-height" property that fits your visual needs

Comment: it makes space in case you use some upper case character - it would be strange if the browser would decide to move text up and down depending on the content. either transform your text with minus padding or better use an image for this purpose if it's a static part of the page